# Python - How to loop through each index position in a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, nlp, linguistics

Given a list `[[["source1"], ["target1"], ["alignment1"]], ["source2"], ["target2"], ["alignment2"]], ...]` , I want to extract the words in the source that align with the words in the target.
For example, in the English-German sentence pair *The hat is on the table . - Der Hut liegt auf dem Tisch .*, I want to print the following:

```
The - Der
hat - Hut
is - liegt
on - auf
the - dem
table - Tisch
. - .
```

So I have written the following:

```
en_de = [
[['The', 'hat', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'table', '.'], ['Der', 'Hut', 'liegt', 'auf', 'dem', 'Tisch', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'], 
[['The', 'picture', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'wall', '.'], ['Das', 'Bild', 'hängt', 'an', 'der', 'Wand', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'], 
[['The', 'bottle', 'is', 'under', 'the', 'sink', '.'], ['Die', 'Flasche', 'ist', 'under', 'dem', 'Waschbecken', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6']
]

for group in en_de:
    src_sent = group[0]
    tgt_sent = group[1]
    aligns = group[2]

    split_aligns = aligns.split()

    hyphen_split = [align.split("-") for align in split_aligns]

    align_index = hyphen_split[0]

    print(src_sent[int(align_index[0])],"-", tgt_sent[int(align_index[1])])
```

This prints, as expected, the words in index position 0 of `src_sent` and `tgt_sent`:

```
The - Der
The - Das
The - Die
```

Now, I don't know how I can print the words of all index positions of `src_sent` and `tgt_sent`. Obviously, I could manually update `align_index` to a new index position for each position in the sentence pair, but on the full dataset, some sentences will have up to 25 index positions.
Is there a way to possibly for-loop through each index position?
When I try:

```
align_index = hyphen_split[0:]
print(src_sent[int(align_index[0])],"-", tgt_sent[int(align_index[1])])
```

I get a `TypeError:  int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`
It's clear that `align_index` can't be a list, but I'm not sure how to convert it into something that will do what I want it to do.
Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All the examples you have provided contain only 1-1 alignments. If this is natural language data, you should have more complex alignments to deal with. Are you only interested in such linear cases, or in the more general word-alignment cases?

Comment: On the line `align_index = hyphen_split[0:]`, you're effectively setting `align_index = [(0,0),(1,1),...]`. Is that what you meant to do? Or did you mean `align_index = hyphen_split[0]`? It's not clear what this line of code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think I just figured it out - what you need is `for align_index in hyphen_split:` followed by your print statement, indented one level deeper.

Comment: @joanis - yes, that's right. The examples are not very complicated, with only 1-1 alignments. The full dataset that I'm working with is NL data, so with one-to-many, many-to-one alignments. That's a bridge I'll cross in the future. And yes, you figured out my problem exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to loop over your `hyphen_split` list:

```
for group in en_de:
    src_sent = group[0]
    tgt_sent = group[1]
    aligns = group[2]

    split_aligns = aligns.split()

    hyphen_split = [align.split("-") for align in split_aligns]

    for align_index in hyphen_split:
        print(src_sent[int(align_index[0])],"-", tgt_sent[int(align_index[1])])
```

See the last two lines, updated from your code.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This is exactly what I was forgetting to do. Many, many thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want this:

```py
en_de = [
    [['The', 'hat', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'table', '.'], ['Der', 'Hut', 'liegt', 'auf', 'dem', 'Tisch', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'],
    [['The', 'picture', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'wall', '.'], ['Das', 'Bild', 'hängt', 'an', 'der', 'Wand', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'],
    [['The', 'bottle', 'is', 'under', 'the', 'sink', '.'], ['Die', 'Flasche', 'ist', 'under', 'dem', 'Waschbecken', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6']
]


for sentences in en_de:
    for en, de in zip(*sentences[:2]):
        print(f'{en} - {de}')
```

Printing pairs of English and German for each sentence. If they are always in pairs this should work. So if the alignment is always linear it is not necessary to have it at all.

If the alignment is not always going to be linear, you would need to account for that too:

```py
en_de = [
    [['The', 'hat', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'table', '.'], ['Der', 'Hut', 'liegt', 'auf', 'dem', 'Tisch', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'],
    [['The', 'picture', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'wall', '.'], ['Das', 'Bild', 'hängt', 'an', 'der', 'Wand', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6'],
    [['The', 'bottle', 'is', 'under', 'the', 'sink', '.'], ['Die', 'Flasche', 'ist', 'under', 'dem', 'Waschbecken', '.'], '0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6']
]


for sentences in en_de:
    # alternative to the below for loop
    # alignment = [(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in [p.split('-') for p in sentences[2].split()]]
    alignment = []
    for pair in sentences[2].split():
        e, g = pair.split('-')
        alignment.append((int(e), int(g)))

    english = [sentences[0][i] for i, _ in alignment]
    german = [sentences[1][i] for _, i in alignment]
    for en, ge in zip(english, german):
        print(f'{en} - {ge}')
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, the alignments are not always one-to-one, so making use of the aligns is very important for my task. 

Do you think it's possible to loop through every index?

Comment: @c_metaphorique edited answer with alignments accounted for, see the second code snippet

Comment: Thank you! This works well, and I'm able to understand it with one exception: what does the underscore _ do? Is it a placeholder? I've never seen it used in such a way before.

Comment: @c_metaphorique sort of, it basically tells Python that it is a throwaway variable, that it won't be used elsewhere so perhaps Python doesn't even bother saving a reference to the object that the underscore would refer to but I don't know about the inner workings, I do know that it basically is used in such cases when that value is not needed/used, as here where the indexes for the other list are not needed (another example would be when you only need to loop a certain amount of times but don't actually need the number for example `for _ in range(5):`)